# passing json objects to a custom jquery plugin. Bad practise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a simple jquery plugin to create a graph.

You can see a basic version of here. http://jsfiddle.net/hqb2W/1/

I'm unsure whether it's bad practice to pass the data to the plugin as I am doing. I'm passing a <strike>json object</strike> an array of javascript objects.

```
$('.bar-container').barGenerator([
        {
            'size'    : 30,
              'class'    : 'points'    
        },
        {
            'size'    : 30,
              'class'    : 'bonus'
        },
        {
            'size'    : 40,
              'class'    : 'extra'
        }
        ]);
```

Looking at my plugin can you see a problem with doing it this way? It seems dangerous to rely on on the strings within the objects. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Why do you consider it dangerous?

Comment: No, you are not using a JSON object. You are using a JavaScript array of JavaScript objects. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: In case someone spells something incorrectly? Perhaps I'm being overly cautious?

Comment: Why do you want users to repeat size and class everywhere? Why not just have array of arrays with 2 elements? Just make it a convention to have first element as size second as class.

Answer (score 0):

> In case someone spells something incorrectly? Perhaps I'm being overly cautious?

Let's put it this way: If you type something incorrectly, like:

```
alret("Hello, world!");
```

Does the JavaScript engine worry about it?